# wcf 4 help page causes System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I would like some assistance in debugging this particular problem.

At some point in time early on in this services lifetime, this help page actually worked http://stephenpattenconsulting.com/Services/help and clicking the links to the various methods produced a service description page. Now all it does is hang, which after turning on tracing, turns out to be a out of memory exception. Now the weird part is these methods all work if I call them programmability.

I have the trace file if you need it.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging I have figure out what caused the issue, turns out it is a known serialization issue with WCF and the Entity Framework when exposing JSON. My particular error is

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

The type 'com.patten.root.Models.FD_GROUP' cannot be serialized to JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does not support references because there is no standardized format for representing references. To enable serialization, disable the IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the type.

Which was why the help page would die.

Please also note that my original post stated that everything "worked" correctly if I hit the endpoint programmatically, that was incorrect, NOT everything was working, specifically this call to the FD_GROUP (FoodGroup).

The way I fixed it was to create DTO's or lighter weight POCO's over my model and expose those when needed.

Take care all.
Stephen